# C++ CLI: How to make a wait timer (possibly in a while loop) without suspending a thread?

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, wait

I will try to describe the problem as best as I can. I have a GUI designed in C++ CLI (Visual Studio 2010) with some OpenGL.

I have a loop, this is what gets done (or should get done):
1. Read line from a file, parse it into parts
2. Call a wait function for a certain period of time - no action to be taken during this period (but GUI should be usable - emergency stop buttons, etc)
3. Once time elapses, go back to reading line from file.

I could definitely do this on the microcontroller side in C using interrupts, but I don't know how to achieve the same thing here. My original idea was to start timer, when the event handler for elapsed time fires, call a function that would in turn call the reading function again. But I don't think that would work well, as at the end of reading the entire file, all those functions will return to their callers. This could also be a mess because file can technically have infinite number of lines (run out of memory with all these calls). What I mean here is basically a huge loop of recursive functions (best I can describe them, where A will call B, but B will call A, after which A calls B again.

I have found this post: [Wait window in a windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181643/wait-window-in-a-windows-application) with the suggestion about using a delegate, but C++ doesn't accept anonymous delegates. I also don't know if this does what I want. Where will the following code snippet return to after time elapses? (I know this is for C#, but the idea should be the same, right?)

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 2000;
t.Tick += delegate { Close(); t.Stop();};
t.Start();
```

I have thought about threading, but I don't know how that will solve my problem. I need the wait timer to trigger another instance of file reading, which would involve calling a function, resulting in my endless function calls worry.

There is also this, that I looked at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx , which uses TimerCallback . But that would suspend the thread until timer fires, right? This would mean that the GUI would be unresponsive.

While unresponsiveness is something I of course want to avoid, I could do it. Or perhaps it is better to put the whole file-reading/waiting block into its own thread and let it delay whatever it wants?

I'd appreciate the advice.

Comment: A GUI timer can only fire when the thread is in a message-processing loop, and after the handler runs, control returns to the message-processing loop.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Thanks, but I'm really confused about what you said. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html

Comment: I am very unsure about how that can help my issue. Waiting for a message to return would still suspend operation (which I don't want). Furthermore, how can I operate the message loop if I don't have any access to WM_?

Comment: You don't operate the message processing loop.  You set up a timer, and the message processing loop will call your function on that time interval.  Every time your function is called, you perform some small amount of work and return.  One timer interval later, you are called back and can continue with the next piece of work.

Comment: But I don't want the message loop to always be on. My goal is to have the wait period only when I call it. I have solved this by using a BackgroundWorker, which lets me have a timer going in a separate thread. The lack of any sort of precision with that timer is going to be a bigger problem now though.

Comment: The message loop is always on if you have a GUI.  Everything else in your program gets called from the main message loop.  Don't you have a call to `Application::Run()` in your `main()` function?

Comment: But if I'm waiting for message loop to receive the timer completion message, I will have to wait in a loop, as illustrated in the link you suggested.

Comment: The loop is provided by the runtime (`Application::Run()` function)  You just need to break your work into chunks, keep track of what chunk you're on, and process one chunk each time your timer event triggers the callback function.  The message loop processes both timer messages and UI events such as mouse clicks.  As long as your timer callback does only a little work before returning, the message loop gets a chance to process UI messages.

Answer (score -1):

while (TimeNotElapsed) 
      Application::DoEvents();